# QMovie.supportedFormats() returns empty list

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, pyside

I am developing an app that uses an animated GIF, read by a `QMovie` and placed in a `QLabel`. When i started trying the app in different environments, i.e. combinations of `PySide` and `PyQt4` on different machines (Win7, OpenSuse) I noticed that sometimes the gif works while other times it doesn't. It does not seem related to which `qt` wrapper I am using.

The only thing I have noticed is that when it does work:

1. `QMovie.isValid()` returns `True`
2. `QMovie.supportedFormats()` returns `[PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('gif'), PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('mng')]`

As opposed to when it does not work:

1. `QMovie.isValid()` returns `False`
2. `QMovie.supportedFormats()` returns `[]`

Any Ideas?

---

**Update: 1**
This problem seems to be consistently associated with the Anaconda installer on both windows and linux. Doesn't matter if it is PySide or PyQt4 though. I did find this issue: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/66.

---

---

Example Code

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class BusyLabel(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, gif, parent = None, text = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.hlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hlayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.hlayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.hlayout)

        # Movie
        self.movieLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.movieLabel.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.movieLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


        self.movie = QtGui.QMovie(gif, QtCore.QByteArray(), self)
        self.movie.setScaledSize(QtCore.QSize(20,20))
        self.movie.setCacheMode(QtGui.QMovie.CacheAll)
        self.movie.setSpeed(100)
        print self.movie.isValid()
        print self.movie.supportedFormats()

        self.movieLabel.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.movieLabel)


        # Label
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(text)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.movie.start()

    def setText(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)

    def start(self):
        self.show()
        self.movie.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.hide()
        self.movie.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gif = os.path.abspath("load.gif")
    print os.path.exists(gif)
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = BusyLabel(gif)
    player.setText('Loading...')
    player.start()
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

gif generated here: http://www.ajaxload.info/

Comment: It requires qgif.dll (in imageformats directory if you deploy it). Do you have this dll on your systems?

Comment: @Chernobyl I found `qgif4.dll` in `...\PySide\plugins\imageformats\`

Comment: When you run this code in your IDE, does your list empty? Or it is empty only when you try run your app as a normal programm (by clicking on exe file for example)

Comment: Its empty when run both ways.

Comment: I think this might be a problem with the Anaconda python installer. It seems to be the common variable.